# How to change container after ontap?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I change the container from
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHwZM.png)

To [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6PB.png)

I tried putting a turnery condition but it says

> error: A value of type 'Row' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'bool'.

Please let me know what I should do..

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code. what did you do so far? please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

based on this error I'd assume you try to get your if statement incorrectly somewhere in the `build` method. I'd advise you to use a function returning widget based on the `onTap` as you're saying.

```
    Widget _dynamicAddButton() {
     if(clickHappened) 
{ return >round widget<} else {return >longWidget<}
    }
```

You can put this function directly in build as it returns widget either way so UI will build correctly.

`clickHappened` being some global bool in the screen widget.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Try to solve your problem**

**Here is Code example:**

```
 bool isContainer=true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     body: Center(
       child: InkWell(
         onTap: (){
           setState(() {
             isContainer=false;
           });
           print("hello tapped");
         },
         child: Container(

           height: 40,
           width: 70,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purple,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
         ),

           child: isContainer?Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [

               Icon(Icons.contact_mail_outlined),
               SizedBox(
                 width: 10,
               ),
               Text("Add")
             ],
           ):Container(
             color: Colors.purple,
             child:Icon(Icons.contact_page_outlined),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
    );
  }
```